# on button click delete from datatable and also from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

foreach row in my table i've a delete button , on click this button i've the following function :

```
function deleteBussDay(jQtable)
{
    var row = jQtable.parentNode.parentNode;
    $(jQtable).closest('tr').remove();
    openHour.splice(row.rowIndex,1);
    // openHour is my array ,which i also want to delete from 
}
```

the problem with this code it does delete the corret row from the table when clicking on delete but it removes the wrong row in the array . (one above of the selected row)
how can i fix it ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, like you say, the correct row is removed, then you make the correct traversal to the table row here:

```
$(jQtable).closest('tr').remove();
```

Meaning, to get the `rowIndex` property of our table row, we can use the same jQuery object together with [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
function deleteBussDay(jQtable) {
    var $row = $(jQtable).closest('tr'), rowInd = $row.prop('rowIndex');
    $row.remove();
    openHour.splice(rowInd ,1);
}
```

Comment: @MaisamMansour Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

'rowIndex' counted for each table.
'rowIndex' changed when you sort table.
As alternative you can use some 'data' attribute as mark.

```
function deleteBussDay(jQtable)
{
    var row = $(jQtable).closest('tr');
    var id = row.data('rowIndex');
    row.remove();
    openHour.splice(id, 1);
    // openHour is my array ,which i also want to delete from 
}
```

or

```
function deleteBussDay(jQtable)
{
    var row = jQtable.parentNode.parentNode;
    var id = row.rowIndex;
    $(row).remove();
    openHour.splice(id, 1);
    // openHour is my array ,which i also want to delete from 
}
```